# Product distribution of X and Y where X is exponentially distributed and Y|X is normally distributed

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have two random variables, X and Y. The variable X has exponential distribution:
$$ X \sim Exp(\lambda).$$ The variable Y is normally distributed conditional on $X$ as follows: $$Y | X \sim N(\mu + k \sigma^2 X, \sigma^2)$$where $k$ is a constant. I am looking for the distribution of their product, $Z = XY$.

I have tried the following: $$f_z(z) = \int_0^\infty f_{Y|X}\left(\frac{z}{x} | x\right)f_X(x)\frac{1}{x} \, dx$$
where $f_{Y|X}$ is the pdf of the normally distributed $Y|X$ and $f_X$ is the pdf of exponentially distributed $X$, but struggled to solve the integral.

Is there a tractable form for this distribution?

Alternatively, is there some other distribution(s) for $X$ which would give a tractable distribution for $Z$? Lognormal? Pareto?

Thanks!

Comment: You may find joint distribution of $X,Y$ and then consider the transformation $(X,Y) \to (X,XY)$

Comment: Hi Prof Shanku, if I do that, it collapses to the same formula as for f_z(z), as above (it was originally missing the 1/x term due to a typo - I've added it back in). Do you know if the consequent integral should be tractable? I end up with an integrand of the form $\frac{1}{x} \exp\left(\frac{a_1}{x^2} + \frac{a_2}{x} + a_3 + a_4 x + a_5 x^2\right)$, which does not appear tractable to me.

Comment: I tried to find the mgf but with no help. Where do you find the question? Is it actually the distribution that was asked for or expectaion or something else?